# My Applications Folder has disappeared from the dock

Tags: macos

Does anyone know why my Applications folders disappeared from the doc and how to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have inadvertently 'poofed' it from the Dock. Just navigate back to

Macintosh HD -> Applications, and drag the Applications folder back into your Dock.